# laravel 5 migration add some primary keys to my database table. how to prevent form it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

When i create Laravel5 migration as follows it adds "linkdesc" column as a primary key. when i read the documentation of laravel5 migration it does not mentioned that `$table->text('description');` this gives a primary key in database.
is there any way to prevent such automatically added primary keys in laravel5 ?
Also is there any other migration functionalities that give this kind of unwanted primary keys ?

my migration is as follows

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->primary(['pemail', 'linkid']);
        $table->bigInteger('linkid');
        $table->string('pemail');
        $table->string('linkname');
        $table->string('linkurl');
        $table->integer('linorder');
        $table->text('linkdesc')->nullable();


    });
```

Comment: Why are you removing the standard `id` primary key?

Comment: I've run this migration and everything is as expected. There is a composite primary key on pemail and linkid, no key on linkdesc.

Comment: @Martin Bean : i have normalized all of my database tables. so i get rid of all unnecessary columns

Comment: @ jedrzej.kurylo : nope.. it still give the problem. please refer this screenshot http://mywebengineer.com/other/stckoverflowImages/lv-migration.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread the info you get in PhpMyAdmin. You have `primary` word inactive without possibility to click on it in the row for `linkdesc` column and you thought Laravel creates primary key for this column.

However the truth is quite different - it's inactive not because Laravel created automatically primary key for this field but because it's a text field and texts fields cannot be primary keys.

You can verify it when you click in PhpMyAdmin on `Indexes` - it should be below the table - there you will see there is no primary key on `linkdesc` column.